# Setting alignment of title text in a JMenu component

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Simply put, JMenu.setHorizontalAligment(SwingConstants.CENTER) does nothing and the text is still left-aligned (using the Windows LAF).

Is there any method of aligning the text in a menu header (not the JMenuItem - the JMenus themselves)?

I'm using JDK1.7.

What my JMenuBar with its JMenus looks like currently:

[image: Current JMenuBar with JMenus (and a single JMenuItem]

Comment: Try setHorizontalTextPosition instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer you beat me to it

Comment: why do you want to surprise your users?

Comment: @Gorb I'm suffering the same thing.  Check out my post on this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728574/centering-text-in-a-jmenu

Comment: As per the answers below, that didn't fix it. I'd tried setHorizontalPosition before I posted here, sorry, I should've clarified.  
@kleopatra I'm not sure what you mean. All I want is a nice little indent (or centering, preferably) to make the menu look a little more professional.

Comment: Also I want to kill this site for not having easy line breaks. Double space does nothing, HTML does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used `CSS` to position and style the text in the menus. `style="text-align:center;"` is the `CSS` used to position the text in the center in the example image at the bottom. In my case, I encapsulated the `JMenu` title in `<p>` paragraph tags;

```
clientFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Client</p></html>");
siteFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Site</p></html>");
employeeFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Employee</p></html>");
jobtypeFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Job Type</p></html>");
```

Which looks like this;

[image]

It's worth noting that in the image above I have also used `width:90px;color:blue;` in the style attribute, but I removed those two styles from the code example above for simplicity. Hope this helps.

This answer is more or less a copy of my original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728574/centering-text-in-a-jmenu/18330229#18330229).

Comment: Thanks, haven't considered that!

Answer (score 1):

Try setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER); followed by invalidate();

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work for me.

Tried calling it on any and all of the JMenus you can see above (mainMenu.setHorizontalTextPosition(etc), mainMenu.invalidate()), no dice.

Answer (score 1):

Had you tried setting [Margin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin(java.awt.Insets)) for the said `JMenu`, if I do this :

```
JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Option");
optionsMenu.setMargin(new Insets(5, 50, 5, 5));
```

This is the output I get :

[image: MARGIN OUTPUT]

[image: MESSENGER IMAGE]

Comment: That doesn't do anything for my layout either. I presume the default behaviour of the Windows LAF is stopping it from doing anything.

I don't think I can do much short of looking into how the Windows LAF is constructed and/or defining my own (not that I ever want to do that in a million years, *shudder*).

Comment: @Gorb : Well if I change my `LookAndFeel` to windows I still get the same result as shown before. Please do have a look at the latest edit, and compare the images, first one is for NIMBUS and second one for WINDOWS.

Comment: As I said, it didn't change anything on my GUI at all unfortunately :(

Are you using Java SE 7?

Comment: Ejaaaaaaaaactly : Here is the version `java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)` on Windows 7 32-bit Platform.