# centering text in a JMenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

Alright, I have been cruising through the net looking for some help with this one, but nothing I try seems to work.  I want to have all of the menu texts centered on their menu buttons.  When I use `setHorizontalTextPosition(JMenu.CENTER)` there is no change.  In fact, regardless of the constant I use, the menu text remains left justified.

Any ideas?

***UPDATE 1**

Still no luck.  After re-reading the JMenu API, I realized that `setHorizontalTextPosition(int)` and `setVerticalTextPosition(int)` only set the text in relation to an icon and `setHorizontalAlignment(int)` and `setVerticalAlignment(int)` set the alignment of both text and icon in the JMenu.

The text positioning methods seem to work as advertised when used with an icon.

The vertical alignment method seems to work on text or icon or both.

However, the horizontal alignment method doesn't seem to work at all.  Even just using it alone on text or icon or both, nothing seems to change.  I have increased the menu size to 150x50 and, no matter the combination, I can't get the text or icon or either to center horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

Going on MadProgrammer's theme of using `HTML`, I used `CSS` to position and style the text in the menus. `style="text-align:center;"` is the `CSS` used to position the text in the center. In my case, I encapsulated the `JMenu` title in a `<p>` paragraph tags inside an `<html>` element;

```
clientFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Client</p></html>");
siteFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Site</p></html>");
employeeFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Employee</p></html>");
jobtypeFilter = new JMenu("<html><p style='text-align:center;'>Job Type</p></html>");
```

Which looks like this;

[image]

It's worth noting that in the image above I have also used `width:90px;color:blue;` in the style attribute, but I removed those two styles from the code example above for simplicity. Hope this helps.

Comment: width:90px; is important

Answer (score 2):

Try `setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);` followed by `invalidate();`

alternatively use [margins](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setMargin%28java.awt.Insets%29):

```
JMenu optionsMenu = new JMenu("Option");
optionsMenu.setMargin(new Insets(5, 50, 5, 5));
```

I made a short SSCCE to see if I could *re-enact* the problem but mine seems perfectly aligned from the start no need for any of the above:

Link to screenshot: http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/1489/67449235.jpg

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JMenuCenterTest extends JFrame {

    public JMenuCenterTest() {
        createUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JMenuCenterTest().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private void createUI() {
        setTitle("JMenu Center Test");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300, 300);
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu1 = new JMenu("File");
        //menu1.setMargin(new Insets(5, 50, 5, 5));
        JMenu menu2 = new JMenu("Options");
        JMenu menu3 = new JMenu("Help");
        //menu1.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        // invalidate();
        bar.add(menu1);
        bar.add(menu2);
        bar.add(menu3);
        getContentPane().add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}
```

Reference:

- [Setting alignment of title text in a JMenu component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712667/setting-alignment-of-title-text-in-a-jmenu-component)

Comment: Your first suggestion gives me this error: {non-static method invalidate() cannot be referenced from a static context} and your second suggestion doesn't center.  I understand I can adjust the Insets, but that's really a good practice.

Comment: why are you calling it from a static method?  make all of the gui's *setup* methods instance methods and then you shouldn't have that problem

Comment: But is the text for each menu centered in the menu button space?  That's what I'm trying to achieve and your picture doesn't show this.

Comment: @meffordm Maybe creating your own [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would make for better help sooner

Comment: I'll upload one when I get home.  BTW, I just tried the invalidate() method and it didn't seem to work either.

Comment: What happens when you change the font?  I'm not sure this is an effective solution to the problem at hand, it assumes to much about the state of UI, IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've played around with this and I've come to the conclusion that I don't think it's possible by setting the properties of the `JMenu`.

Anything you do is been overridden by the UI delegate.

Try this:

```
JMenu menu = new JMenu("<html><table width='100%'><tr><td halign='center' align='center' bgcolor='red'>File</td></tr></table></html>");

menuBar.add(menu);
```

You find that no matter how wide you make the menu, the area supplied to the text is ALSO just large enough to render it.

[image: Example of menu text]

The only choice I can see you have left is to supply your own UI delegate which is IMHO a really, really bad idea which will only eventually blow up in your face, but that's just my opinion :P

Comment: Yeah, I just finished testing several combos with the same results.  Frustrating.

Comment: I both love & hate the UI delegate system

Answer (score 1):

I think `setHorizontalAlignment` should do what you want whereas `setHorizontalTextPosition` specifies text position relative to an icon.

Comment: See the link I provided in my reference specifically the question. Dont think that will work either: "Simply put, JMenu.setHorizontalAligment(SwingConstants.CENTER) does nothing and the text is still left-aligned (using the Windows LAF)." but I could be wrong

Comment: Good point. I actually had luck with this a while back, but it seems like it may not work with more recent java versions.

Comment: @bcr Do you happen to remember your setup when you had this working?

Comment: Your problem might come down to the restrictions of the Look and Feel

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm using Nimbus, but I also tried the default with now difference.

Comment: I think the problem is that from the point of the component, the text is been aligned.  This seems to becoming down to how the UI decides how to layout the individual components of the menu.  `JMenu` extends from `JMenuItem`, `JMenuItem` has some additional layout elements, check boxes, icons, shortcuts.  When the UI looks at the `JMenu`, it is only assigning enough space for the text to fill out, not the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

So the solution is:

```
private JMenuBar menu;
private JMenu file;

Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
double height = (double)screenSize.getHeight();
double widht = (double)screenSize.getWidth();

double frameh = 0.3*height; int frameH =(int)Math.ceil(frameh);
double framew = 0.3*widht;  int frameW = (int)Math.ceil(framew);

double menuh = 0.1*frameh;      int menuH = (int)Math.ceil(menuh);
double menuw = framew;          int menuL = frameW;

double fileh = menuh;       int fileH = menuH;
double filew = 0.1*menuw;   int fileW = (int)Math.ceil(filew);

    int textPos= fileW-10; //at the start of the button you have a little margin and you must leave somme pixel to fixe the center.

Window(){

    initialisation();
    construction();

    this.setTitle("Tutoriel 1.3 HS");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(frameW, frameH);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public void initialisation(){       
    file = new JMenu(("<html><table width='"+textPos+"'><tr><td align='center'>File</td></tr></table></html>"));// this is accept


    file.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(fileW, fileH));
    menu = new JMenuBar();
    menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(menuL, menuH));
    menu.add(file);     
}

public void construction(){
    this.setJMenuBar(menu);
}
```